# How to use an .net assembly installed in GAC in my project

Tags: .net, asp.net

i need to refer an assembly installed in the GAC in my project.
can any body explain me the steps for using the assembly installed in GAC.

thanking you.

Comment: Assemblies you see when you choose Project + Add Reference is not created from the GAC. You should keep a copy of the assemblies stored in any location other than the GAC. Microsoft stores them in c:\windows\microsoft.net and c:\program files\reference assemblies. Using either the Project or the Browse tab is the most common way to add the reference or hack the registry. The GAC is however most typically used on the target machine, not your dev machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [How to reference Assemblies in the GAC](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=1175):

> We have been getting some posts lately
>   where developers are installing
>   assemblies in the GAC and then asking
>   why they don't see them enumerated in
>   the Add Reference dialogs. This should
>   clear things up for most developers.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

What in the Case, if i dont have the copy of assembly installed in the GAC. and usually developers wont have permissions to modify the registry keys.

Comment: You have two objections to the article.  On the first issue, you can browse to the virtual folder.  c:\windows\assembly\GAC .. or GAC_32.  (on a 32-bit machine).  On the second, tough luck.

Comment: @AndrewHare Is the [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=1175) dead?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to right click your project and to choose `Add reference...`; that .NET tab should contains all GAC registered assemblies. You don't need to have a DLL copy, nor to access windows folder.

If this doesn't works, so you have a machine setup problem, and will need to contact your desktop support personnel, or to follow @[Andrew answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115259/how-to-use-an-net-assembly-installed-in-gac-in-my-project/2115273#2115273)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sexy visual studio extension that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879/) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

[image]