# How to use assembly registered in GAC on MonoDevelop?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, .net-assembly

I recently [registered Mysql.Data.dll assembly in GAC on 64bit Ubuntu 14.4](http://xameeramir.github.io/install-mysql-ubuntu-linux/) to use it following [this example](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/mysql/) with an [ASP.NET Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/) and [verified](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-176658.html).

[image: registered Mysql.Data.dll assembly in GAC linux]

I realized that although it is registered in GAC, it's [not directly usable from Edit references dialogue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998375/2404470) on [Monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/).

[image: Mysql not found in Edit references dialogue on Monodevelop]

I tried to see how can this be [made possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115273/2404470), the [possibilities exists for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396794/2404470)  which is something I don't need.

Doubts:

- If the assembly is [un-usable](http://www.monodevelop.com/help/faq/#i-added-an-assembly-to-the-gac-why-doesnt-it-appear-in-the-assemblies-list-when-i-try-to-add-a-reference-in-a-monodevelop-project) what is the [**concept** of registering it in GAC](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/mysql/)?
- [How can this assembly be provided by a package (and advertised through a `.pc` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998375/2404470)
- How can this assembly be bundled together with the application?
- Are the steps I followed incorrect?

Comment: Just go to the `.Net Assembly` tab of the `Edit References` dialog and add a direct file-based reference to where your local copy of `Mysql.Data.dll` assembly is. `Bundling` is another topic, but if you are just copying CIL exe/dll assemblies flag it as 'local copy' and it will be placed along side the rest of your output files. No need to register it in the GAC at all, in fact, you really should not ever have the need to register anything in the GAC.

Comment: @SushiHangover Do you ever sleep? :D

Comment: No ;-) Hopefully that helped.

Comment: Yeah! I was able to add the reference but unable to recognize `IDbConnection`, `MySqlConnection`, `IDbCommand` and `IDataReader` etcetra as described in [this example](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/mysql/)

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Data` and make sure that you have a `using System.Data;` statement as those interfaces (IDbConnection, IDataReader, ...) are located in that **standard** framework assembly (GAC-based...). I am using `mysql-connector-net-6.9.8-noinstall` and that example in the link you provided should compile. Now running it of course depends upon a test db, employee table, and correct uid/passwd setup...

Comment: @SushiHangover Oops! `System.Data` was indeed not referenced. I'm unable to understand why `using System.Data;` didn't thrown any error.

Comment: @SushiHangover The problem looks solved, now whenever I try to add the reference `MySql.Data.dll` is [always shown in **.NET Assembly** tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ADYpH.png)